# How to use $_SESSION in laravel to add items to cart

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I would love to use the above code in Laravel the same way I use that `$_SESSION` in normal `php`. So I need help on how to convert such to Laravel. I am only try to add stuff to cart.

```
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
    if($_POST["action"] == "add")
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
        {
            $is_available = 0;

            foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
            {
                if($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_id'] == $_POST["product_id"])
                {
                    $is_available++;

                    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] + $_POST["product_quantity"];
                }
            }

            if($is_available == 0)
            {
                $item_array = array(
                    'product_id'       => $_POST["product_id"],
                    'product_name'     => $_POST["product_name"],
                    'product_price'    => $_POST["product_price"],
                    'product_quantity' => $_POST["product_quantity"]
                );

                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $item_array;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $item_array = array(
                'product_id'       => $_POST["product_id"],
                'product_name'     => $_POST["product_name"],
                'product_price'    => $_POST["product_price"],
                'product_quantity' => $_POST["product_quantity"]
            );

            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $item_array;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to convert.

Comment: Nope SO is not meant to provide code for you, try, learn and if you have issues with an error code then you could post a question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Laravel session documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session).

I think what you will be using is `session()->has()` and `session()->push()`.